Why does the base color ,in material, for my object (Donut) keep changing color?
As you can see the Ive been learning blender form the BlenderGurus how to make a donut videos. Ive been having a pretty smooth run of it, so far its been enjoyable. But Ive run into this problem with the color of my donut!
The donut color used to be pink. I changed it to a tan-ish color, not to long ago in the donut making process, to make it look more like a real donut.
For some reason it kept changing back to pink and then back to the tan-ish color I changed it too, while Im progressing my creation, doing different things. I was just excited to move forward, so I just kinda chopping it up to technical difficulties, it fixes itself so didnt seem like the biggest problem.
But now its irritating because i don't know why it's happening, and the color in the material section says it's the color I changed it too, but it's displayed diffrently .
Plus Ive added texture paint that is no longer visible, which is really annoying!
I tried saving and closing it to see if it would fix it self as it has previously (just randomly I might add) , but it hasnt.
Im hoping its not permanent, and perhaps its a quick fix Im just unaware of.
If anyone knows what to do please let me know. 

The pink/purple color indicates a "missing" texture.
You don't have material color, you have an "image texture".
Your file is losing reference to the image file, that usually happens if the file is not in the same directory of your donut.blend file.
If you move the image file there and reassign the texture to the new path, it will probably solve.
Alternatively, you can pack your images into the .blend file. It will make the file bigger, but you will never lose reference. How to pack images into blend file

Moller you've been a great help! I found that my texture file was seen as 'missing', so following your advice I packed the images into the blend file and located the missing file manually. My project is back on track!               _Thank you!
